# Estrutura de Pastas MVC

Tags: php, mvc, front-end, back-end

Olá. Estou querendo construir minha própria aplicação usando o padrão MVC. Entendo a separação de cada item(Model, View e Controller). Porém quero fazer algum tipo de separação entre o Front-end e o Back-end, já que alguns Controllers do backend terão o mesmo nome que os do Frontend.

Não consigo visualizar algo que seja mais simples para criar essa restrição. Alguém tem idéia de como fazer?

[image: Estrutura básica do frontend]

Comment: O que chamas de "controler do front-end"? os que são usados com ajax?

Comment: Deve existir umas 5 ou 6 perguntas iguais ou muito parecidas com esta.

Comment: Não é algo simples de explicar, mas acredito que o conjunto de classes aqui https://github.com/szagot/config irá te ajudar a afazer separação, em especial a classe Uri (https://github.com/szagot/config#uri).

Comment: Sergio, controllers do frontend são as manipulações do PHP com o banco de dados que geram o as informações para printar no HTML do View

Comment: @Szag-Ot na verdade preciso de uma separação física entre o Frontend e o Backend

Comment: @ThiagodaVictóriaNunes neste caso é só criar o "admin" (o q vc está chamando de backend) com a mesma estrutura, tratando o /admin/ (ou o nome q desejar) como um sistema em separado, com seu proprio htaccess (se aplicavel). Daí é só definir uma pasta para os crontollers em comum.

Comment: @Szag-Ot Onde colocaria esse admin para substituir o backed?

Comment: @ThiagodaVictóriaNunes na propria raiz... ou em qualquer outro lugar que preferir. A estrutura dentro de admin/ seria a mesma que a da pasta raiz, porém os crontrollers de models seriam do administrativo, ao passo que na raiz seriam do acesso ao público (loja, blog, etc...).

Comment: @Szag-Ot Entendo. Minha dívida é: Precisarei de Views, de Controllers e do Model(esse pode ser um só, tanto para frontend quanto backend/admin) Eu criaria outras pastas de controller e de views dentro da pasta admin? [Estou procurando a maneira mais inteligente de criar esses mecanismos]

Comment: @ThiagodaVictóriaNunes eu acredito que depende muito da sua regra de negócio. Mas normalmente os models que regem as regras de negocio devem ficar em um único lugar. Isso não deve ser um problema se vc estiver seguindo um padrão como PSR-0 ou PSR-4 (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/). Você sepra aprenas os controllers e as views, uma vez que estas são individuais, alvo tavez pelos controllers, que você tb pode definir todas na raiz, deixando apenas as views em separado. Vou ver se consigo um tempo pra poder criar um modelo generico de divisao pra ti

Comment: @Szag-Ot Certo. Obrigado cara. Estou acostumado a ter Controllers e Views de Frontend e Backend separados, assim como os arquivos js, css e outros. Queria criar uma estrutura diferente dessa. Agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Recomendo explorar os generators do Yeoman, como por exemplo o [generator-angular-php](https://github.com/amercier/generator-angular-php) e [generator-angular-fullstack](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

Comment: @BrunoWego Vou anotar aqui. Obrigado.

Answer (score 7):

Em minha experiência, o problema desta estruturação sempre ocorre com as views, uma vez que 50 views poderá utilizar apenas 1 controller e 1 model, portanto minha sugestão e como trabalho com meu próprio framework, é justamente separar somente as views ficando mais ou menos assim, baseado em sua estrutura:

```
app
   controllers
   models
   views
      admin (Backend)
         produtos
            add_produtos.phtml
            edit_produtos.phtml
            list_produtos.phtml
            del_produtos.phtml
         usuarios
            add_usuarios.phtml
            edit_usuarios.phtml
            list_usuarios.phtml
            del_usuarios.phtml     
      site (Frontend)
            home.phtml
            empresa.phtml
            clientes.phtml
            contato.phtml
```

Comment: Entendi sua colocação. Obrigado Thyago!